# Como Executar o Pivotal TC Server com o Eclipse Luna?

Tags: spring, jee, workspace, spring-tools-suite

Estou estudando o uso do Spring Security, e conforme o tutorial neste link, é preciso usar o [STS - Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools), porém como já tenho minha instalação do Eclipse de uso diário, instalei os plugins do Spring e também o Connector para Pivotal TC Server, mas ao tentar executar a aplicação com a instancia criada do Server, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal Servers.Pivotal.pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE.PivotalTCServer_1.conf.logging.properties

Abaixo segue a tela de meu ambiente, caso seja preciso mais alguma informação por favor use o comentário solicitando.

[image: Tela de Trabalho]

- Eclipse Luna SR 2 (4.4.2)
- Plugin Spring IDE 3.7.0
- Pivotal TC Server Integration For Eclipse 3.7.0
- Pivotal TC Server Spring Insight Integration Fro Eclipse 3.7.0
- Pivotal TC Server Developer 3.1.1

O que está errado?